# Use angular pipe to insert DOM clones

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe, angular-routerlink

I'm using angular 5 and I want to dynamically clone DOM templates using a pipe:

```
<div id="template" style="display:none;">
   <a routerlink="{{parameter.route}}">here</a>
</div>

<nav> id="menuItem">
    {{parameter.text | insertTemplatePipe }}
</nav>
```

parameter.text contains a value such as:

`Please click {{insertTemplate}} to go to the next page.`

And I want to use the pipe to replace the substring `{{insertTemplate}}` with the contents of `<div id=template">` and most importantly, I expect the routerlink of the anchor tag to work.

I read about accessing in components, such as explained [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-components/elementref.html), but how can I achieve this in a pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Pipes transform strings into strings, they are not meant to know about DOM. You should create a component.

```
<menulink [text]="parameter.text"></menulink>
```

Just "ng generate component MenuLink"

Add your html to the template and and text as an input in the typescript.

```
@Input text;
```